# TF_RECORDS are not produced after I run the generate_tfrecord.py script

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tfrecord

When I run the following script in jupyter notebook, on my mac m1, it runs (star comes on then off to show its done running), however, when I check my annotations file, there are no tf records:

```
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'train')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'train.record')} 
!python {files['TF_RECORD_SCRIPT']} -x {os.path.join(paths['IMAGE_PATH'], 'test')} -l {files['LABELMAP']} -o {os.path.join(paths['ANNOTATION_PATH'], 'test.record')}
```

I have also tried to create the tf records, by first creating the csv files then running 'generate_tfrecord.py', (from this link [https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py](https://stackoverflow.com) ) but I get the following error :

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv
```

Comment: This won't help in this case because your environment doesn't match what the script wants, but in general `!python` should be replaced by `%run` when working in Jupyter. The magic `%run` command handles communication in the various channels better and offers more features. See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) for more about it.